# Angular Momentum and Eigenfunctions in QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum

In Griffith's Quantum book, he starts off by finding the commutation relationships between the angular momentum and its components. He then goes on to find the uncertainty relationship

$$\sigma_{L_x}\sigma_{L_y} \geq \frac{\hbar}{2} \lvert \langle L{z} \rangle \rvert$$

What I am having trouble with is his next sentence (since they are incompatible observables):"It would therefore be futile to look for states that are simultaneously eigenfunctions of $L_x$ and $L_y$."

I am trying to think of this in terms of incompatible observables that I am more comfortable thinking about, namely $p_x$ and $x$. What would the corresponding eigenfunctions be in this case? In the end we do find simultaneous eigenfunctions for $L_z$ and $L^2$ (since these do commute) which turns out to be the spherical harmonics.

Comment: 1. Why are you more comfortable thining about $x$ and $p_x$ than $L_x,L_y$? The position and momentum operators have far more subtle issues (like their "eigenstates" not belonging to the actual space, or them not being defined on the whole space,...) than the angular momentum operators. 2. You can find in every QM book the relation $\langle p \vert x \rangle \propto \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}xp/\hbar}$ between momentum and position "eigenstates" 3. I'm not sure what exactly you are asking for - eigenfunctions *of which operator* do you want, and what is keeping you from computing those yourself.

Comment: I guess I was spitting information more than asking a question. We do end up getting the spherical harmonics which are simultaneous eigenfunctions of $L_z$ and $L^2$ with eigenvalues $m \hbar$ and $l(l+1) \hbar^2$ respectively.The question I'm having is why do we want _simultaneous_ eigenfunctions?

Comment: Because [complete sets of commuting observables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_set_of_commuting_observables) are nice.

Comment: Griffith's  sentence is at least imprecise: the fact that two observables are not compatible does not mean that there are no common eigenvectors. Indeed, there could be  infinitely many common eigenvectors of $L_x$ and $L_y$, depending on the physical system. What is impossible is finding a Hilbert basis of common eigenvectors.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question in your comment: consider the hamiltonion of a particle in a central force field:

$$H=-\frac{\hbar}{2m}\nabla^2+V(r)= \frac{1}{2m}P_r^2+\frac{L^2}{2mr^2}+V(r),$$

where $P_r=-i\hbar~ r^{-1}\partial_r r $ is the radial momentum operator.  Let's operate with this Hamiltonion on some wavefuncton $\psi$:

$$\left[ \frac{1}{2m}P_r^2+\frac{L^2}{2mr^2}+V(r) \right]\psi=E \psi.$$

This equation is of the form

$$(\text{Operator 1}+\text{Operator 2}+\text{Number})\cdot\psi=\text{Number}\cdot \psi. $$

Next we know that $H,L^2$ and $L_z$ commute, so we can write $\psi$ as a product of the radial wavefunctions and the spherical harmonics: $\psi_{Elm}=R_E(r)Y_{lm}(\theta,\phi$) such that we can write our equation as

$$\left[ \frac{1}{2m}P_r^2+\frac{l(l+1)\hbar^2}{2mr^2}+V(r) \right]\psi_{Elm}=E \psi_{Elm},$$

which is of the form

$$(\text{Operator}+\text{Number}+\text{Number})\cdot\psi=\text{Number}\cdot \psi. $$

We see that the advantage of simultaneous eigenfunctions of operators is that we can exchange the operators with the associated eigenvalues, i.e. we exchange operators for numbers. In this example here we exchanged the expression for $L^2$ (operator) for it's associated eigenvalues $l(l+1)\hbar^2$ (numbers), since $\psi$ is a simultaneous eigenfunction of the *whole* Hamiltonian and $L^2$. There are other examples like this, and in the end it's the same procedure: the hamiltonian is written containing some operators. After some arguments it's said that "operator x" and "operator y" commute so that we can replace "operator x" and "operator y" by the corresponding eigenvalues.